# Can't set any 'checked' value using JQuery/Telerik in IE 11

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, telerik

### The Issue

In a user control (.ascx), I have a certain radio button list with two Radio buttons with values "On" and "Off", that when clicked I'd like it to set the selected radio button for some other radio buttons that also have the same "On" and "Off".

When the controlling radio button list is set to "On", i'd like to check the "Off" radio in those dependent radio buttons.  And when it is set to "Off", switch those dependent ones back to "On".

Additionally I have some checkboxes that need to respond to the same controlling "On"/"Off" as well.  They should become unchecked when it is "On" and checked when it is "Off".

### What I have now

Below is what I have.  **It is working just fine in Chrome and Firefox, but not IE 11**

In Page_Load() I have:

```
 Me.rblController.Items(0).Attributes.Add("OnClick", "ToggleOtherStuff();")
 Me.rblController.Items(1).Attributes.Add("OnClick", "ToggleOtherStuff();")
```

Each radio button list to respond the controller rbl looks like this, they have class "customerRadioButtonList":

```
   <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblCustomer1" CssClass="customerRadioButtonList" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
                <asp:ListItem>On</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>Off</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:RadioButtonList>
```

The checkboxes are simple as well, they have class "AlertsCheckBox":

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="cbxAlertCheck1" CssClass="AlertsCheckBox" runat="server" />
```

Here's the function that runs in response to the clicks of the controller radios:

```
function ToggleOtherStuff() {        

    if ($telerik.$('#<%=rblController.ClientID%> input[type="radio"][value="On"]').first().is(':checked')) {          

        alert('On Clicked'); // This fires OK in IE too

        $telerik.$('.customerRadioButtonList input[type="radio"][value="Off"]').prop('checked', true);                      

        $telerik.$('AlertsCheckBox input').prop('checked', false);

    } else {

        $telerik.$('.customerRadioButtonList input[type="radio"][value="On"]').each(function () {
            if (this.disabled == false) {
                this.checked = true;
            }

        });

        $telerik.$('AlertsCheckBox input').each(function () {
            if (this.disabled == false) {
                this.checked = true;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I'm completely stumped why this is not working in IE.  I thought maybe the Telerik Ajax is to blame, I removed the AjaxManagerProxy in the .aspx of the page that uses this control, but that had no affect. The events are firing fine as I can see because of some debug alerts(); I put in.

I also verified that the Jquery selectors I'm using do return values, and I can even read the 'checked' property values.  **But I can't set the 'checked' property**.  Setting it is having no effect, all radio buttons and checkboxes are not changing.  What's going on?

Comment: I've confirmed that the presence of RadFormDecorator on the page causes this issue.  Trying to figure out why...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this is a Telerik issue:

http://www.telerik.com/forums/setting-checked-property-to-decorated-checkboxes-with-javascript-not-working-on-ie11

Comment: And it is fixed, so upgrading to the latest version should get you fixed up http://feedback.telerik.com/Project/108/Feedback/Details/89098-fix-checkboxes-that-are-checked-dynamically-are-not-styled-correctly-by-the-form

Comment: Yup, we just upgraded and the issue is fixed.  Thanks!